# Enumerate "Godmode" in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

For a search application I'm currently trying to index the "Godmode" special folder that Windows includes for its own search capabilities.

Using the great `Vanara.Windows.Shell` library I'm currently able to index my desktop, but once I try to index the Godmode folder the enumeration doesn't yield any items. I tried running the IDE as an Administrator user but that did not fix it.

Here is the code I'm currently working with:

```
void Main()
{
    Shell32.IShellFolder desktopShellFolder;
    Shell32.SHGetDesktopFolder(out desktopShellFolder);

    Shell32.PIDL ppidl;
    Shell32.SFGAO psfgaoOut;
    Shell32.SHParseDisplayName("shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}", IntPtr.Zero, out ppidl, (Shell32.SFGAO)0, out psfgaoOut);

    var godmodeShellFolder = (Shell32.IShellFolder)desktopShellFolder.BindToObject(ppidl, null, new Guid("000214E6-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"));
    CollectSearchItems(godmodeShellFolder, ppidl);
}

void CollectSearchItems(Shell32.IShellFolder shellFolder, Shell32.PIDL pidl)
{
    var itemEnum = shellFolder.EnumObjects(IntPtr.Zero, Shell32.SHCONTF.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS | Shell32.SHCONTF.SHCONTF_FOLDERS);

    IntPtr itemId;
    uint fetched;
    while (itemEnum.Next(1, out itemId, out fetched) == HRESULT.S_OK)
    {
        Shell32.SFGAO sfgao = Shell32.SFGAO.SFGAO_FOLDER | Shell32.SFGAO.SFGAO_STREAM | Shell32.SFGAO.SFGAO_LINK;
        shellFolder.GetAttributesOf(1, new IntPtr[] { itemId }, ref sfgao);

        if ((sfgao & Shell32.SFGAO.SFGAO_FOLDER) == 0)
        {
            var childPidl = new Shell32.PIDL(itemId);
            var itemName = shellFolder.GetDisplayNameOf(childPidl, Shell32.SHGDNF.SHGDN_INFOLDER | Shell32.SHGDNF.SHGDN_NORMAL);
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace
`CollectSearchItems(godmodeShellFolder, ppidl);` with `CollectSearchItems(desktopShellFolder, ppidl);` I can successfully enumerate my desktop, so I think I'm pretty close...

Why does enumerating the Godmode folder not work, and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: The code is based on this [project](https://github.com/madnessw/thesnow)

Comment: When I try the code it does the same thing for both folders, it enumerates successfully, but the name is always null. I don't know about this vanara addin (your code *seems* ok, but I don't understand why name is null... didn't investigate vanara), but anyway, you don't need it to enumerate a folder. This code does it w/o any 3rd party: https://pastebin.com/C5B5xjcq

Comment: This is a thousand times simpeler than the P/Invoke I came up with. Thank you very much @SimonMourier! It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions:

- Run my application in x64/AnyCPU mode instead of x86, now the enumerator actually finds elements and I can query their name. This gives me the results I'm expecting.
- The solution from @SimonMourier. This code is a lot simpler and works great!